# How to add value into stacked bar chart in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, stacked-bar-chart

I have the dataset as follow, I want to plot stack bar chart with the value at center of bar chart:

```
20×6 DataFrame
 Row │ size             year   mean_turnover  size_string      year_string  mean_turnover_string 
     │ String31         Int64  Float64        String31         String       String
─────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ Quy mô vừa        2017          187.1  Quy mô vừa       2017         187.1
   2 │ Quy mô vừa        2018          186.1  Quy mô vừa       2018         186.1
   3 │ Quy mô vừa        2019          115.7  Quy mô vừa       2019         115.7
   4 │ Quy mô vừa        2020          103.5  Quy mô vừa       2020         103.5
   5 │ Quy mô vừa        2021          133.3  Quy mô vừa       2021         133.3
   6 │ Quy mô siêu nhỏ   2017           83.7  Quy mô siêu nhỏ  2017         83.7
   7 │ Quy mô siêu nhỏ   2018           78.0  Quy mô siêu nhỏ  2018         78.0
   8 │ Quy mô siêu nhỏ   2019           82.7  Quy mô siêu nhỏ  2019         82.7
   9 │ Quy mô siêu nhỏ   2020           81.0  Quy mô siêu nhỏ  2020         81.0
  10 │ Quy mô siêu nhỏ   2021           92.6  Quy mô siêu nhỏ  2021         92.6
  11 │ Quy mô nhỏ        2017          176.4  Quy mô nhỏ       2017         176.4
  12 │ Quy mô nhỏ        2018          171.9  Quy mô nhỏ       2018         171.9
  13 │ Quy mô nhỏ        2019           98.0  Quy mô nhỏ       2019         98.0
  14 │ Quy mô nhỏ        2020           91.5  Quy mô nhỏ       2020         91.5
  15 │ Quy mô nhỏ        2021          102.0  Quy mô nhỏ       2021         102.0
  16 │ Quy mô lớn        2017          165.5  Quy mô lớn       2017         165.5
  17 │ Quy mô lớn        2018          170.6  Quy mô lớn       2018         170.6
  18 │ Quy mô lớn        2019          156.6  Quy mô lớn       2019         156.6
  19 │ Quy mô lớn        2020          137.6  Quy mô lớn       2020         137.6
  20 │ Quy mô lớn        2021          122.0  Quy mô lớn       2021         122.0
```

Here is my code:

```
using DataFrames, Gadfly 

turnover_size_df = DataFrame(size = ["Quy mô vừa", "Quy mô vừa", "Quy mô vừa", "Quy mô vừa", "Quy mô vừa", "Quy mô siêu nhỏ", "Quy mô siêu nhỏ", "Quy mô siêu nhỏ", "Quy mô siêu nhỏ", "Quy mô siêu nhỏ", "Quy mô nhỏ", "Quy mô nhỏ", "Quy mô nhỏ", "Quy mô nhỏ", "Quy mô nhỏ", "Quy mô lớn", "Quy mô lớn", "Quy mô lớn", "Quy mô lớn", "Quy mô lớn"],
               year = [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021],
               mean_turnover = [187.1, 186.1, 115.7, 103.5, 133.3, 83.7, 78.0, 82.7, 81.0, 92.6, 176.4, 171.9, 98.0, 91.5, 102.0, 165.5, 170.6, 156.6, 137.6, 122.0])

p_turnover_s = plot(turnover_size_df,
                x = "year",
                y = "mean_turnover",
                color = "size",
                Geom.bar(position=:stack),
                Guide.xlabel("Year"),
                Guide.ylabel("Turnover Rate"),
                label = "mean_turnover_string",
                Geom.label(position=:above),
                Scale.x_continuous(format = :plain),
                Scale.x_continuous(minvalue=2017, maxvalue=2021),
                Theme(
                background_color = "white",
                bar_spacing = 2mm 
    )        
)
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Desired output:

[image: here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there... Use strings for `label` and add `Stat.dodge(position=:stack)` as a parameter to the function call.

```
labels = map(string, turnover_size_df.mean_turnover)

plot(turnover_size_df,
    x = :year,
    y = :mean_turnover,
    color = :size,
    Guide.xlabel("Year"),
    Guide.ylabel("Turnover Rate"),
    label = labels, 
    Geom.label(position=:centered),
    Stat.dodge(position=:stack),
    Geom.bar,
    Scale.x_continuous(format = :plain),
    Scale.x_continuous(minvalue=2017, maxvalue=2021),
    Theme(
    background_color = "white",
    bar_spacing = 2mm 
    )        
)
```

Result:

[image: stacked bar chart with labels]

As the help (`?`) for `Stat.doge` states:

> Transform the points in the x and y aesthetics into set of dodged or stacked points in the x and y aesthetics. position is :dodge or :stack. ...

Minor note: Specifying `position=:stack` for `Geom.bar` is not necessary as `color` is already defined.